# WPF set attached event programmatically

Tags: wpf, events, code-behind, attached-properties

How do you do this programmatically in WPF?

```
<window Validation.Error="ItemError"></Window>
```

I am trying to set the attached event for Validation.Error through code, but cannot quite figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use [Validation.AddErrorHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validation.adderrorhandler.aspx) to do this:

```
Validation.AddErrorHandler(this, this.ItemError);
```